# drawing bug in self-made paint application

Tags: java, graphics

I have a stupid bug i cant figure out in the Paint-like application developed in Java. My problem is now that when i draw shapes (let say rectangles) the rectangle should be drawing in all 4 directions (whatever way is dragged), but now its drawing only in the down-right direction. I coded it to be all directions. While figuring out the error i realized that when you drag up-left the initial x and y take value of the x2, y2. I have no idea why its happening as i have no code that is doing that. Please help, I ve been on this bug all night ((

this class is responsible for all the shapes

```
public abstract class DrawShapes implements DrawListenerInterface {

private final Canvas canvas;

protected int x;
protected int y;
protected int x2;
protected int y2;
protected int w;
private boolean prev;

protected int h;

public DrawShapes(Canvas canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
}

@Override
public void preview(Graphics2D g2) {
    g2.setColor(Color.black);
    if (prev) {
        draw(g2);
    }
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {

    System.out.println("before " + x + " " + y + " " + x2 + " " + y2);
    x = Math.min(x, x2);
    y = Math.min(y, y2);
    w = Math.abs(x - x2);
    h = Math.abs(y - y2);
    //
    System.out.println("after " + x + " " + y + " " + x2 + " " + y2);

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    prev = true;

    this.x = e.getX();
    this.y = e.getY();
    this.x2 = e.getX();
    this.y2 = e.getY();
    System.out.println("PRESSED " + x + " " + x2 + " " + y + " " + y2);

    canvas.repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    // this.x2 = e.getX();
    // this.y2 = e.getY();
    final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) canvas.getImage().getGraphics();
    canvas.defaultSettings(g2);
    prev = false;
    draw(g2);
    // canvas.repaint();

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    this.x2 = e.getX();
    this.y2 = e.getY();
    System.out.println("dragging " + x2 + " " + y2);
    this.canvas.repaint();

}
```

this class is the child class of DrawShapes that is drawing its own shape

```
public class SquareListener extends DrawShapes {



@Override
public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.draw(g2);
        g2.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
// System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + x2 + " " + y2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare X1 with X2 and Y1 with Y2 and in case when *1 > *2 - swap them for drawRect().

Comment: that's exactly what i am doing

Comment: Ok. I have not read everything. The problem is that you first get `x = Math.min(x,x2)` and then `w = Math.abs(x-x2)`. Swap them, i.e. first `abs` then `min`. Now when x2 < x you have w = 0.

Comment: I have never felt so dumb in my entire career ((( thanx you r awesome